# File Chooser is unable to open my file

Tags: java, jfilechooser

So I'm having this problem recently where my txt file won't open up.
I'm not sure exactly where I went wrong. Here is the code from my file chooser class.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class FileChooser {

public static void emailFile(JTextArea textRecepients) throws IOException {
    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();  
    chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File("."));
    chooser.setFileFilter(new javax.swing.filechooser.FileFilter() {

        public boolean accept(File f) {
            return f.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".txt")
            || f.isDirectory();
        }

        public String getDescription() {
            return "txt file";
        }
    });

    int r = chooser.showOpenDialog(new JFrame());
    if (r == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        String name = chooser.getSelectedFile().getName();
        System.out.println(name);
        String line;
        try {
            FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(name);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

            while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                textRecepients.setText(line);
            }
            bufferedReader.close();         
        } catch(FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println("Unable to open file '" + name + "'");                
        }
    }
}
```

It's supposed to use the `JFileChooser` to get my txt file and print the contents line by line in a `JTextArea`.

Comment: what happens when you run the code?

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code in a debugger?

Comment: did you get it working?

Comment: Yes i stepped through the code with a debugger it will get to the FileReader(name);  line and then it just skips to the file not found exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use

```
String path = chooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();
```

instead of getting the name.

The problem is that each time you loop you overwrite the text:

```
while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    textRecepients.setText(line);
}
```

Use a `StringBuilder`:
(before the `try` block):

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
```

and then in the block:

```
while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    sb.append(line+"\n");
}
textRecepients.setText(sb.toString());
...
```

Comment: Thanks for reminding me about string builder! :p sometimes i just blank out.

Comment: i stepped through the code with a debugger it will get to the FileReader(name); line and then it just skips to the file not found exception.

Comment: Well, that is becausr you wrote a path that doesn't exist. You unaccepted the answer because of this? (I might be confusing questions, so I just want to be sure)

Comment: oh i thought FileChooser allowed you to select a file in any path. i was trying to open a txt file on my dsesktop. i guess i have to put the file in my src folder

Comment: @Fallspell Updated my answer